# Certificate expiration

Tags: android-emulator

I am unable to launch my apps on an Android emulator anymore due to "Error generating final archive: Debug Certificate expired on 4/15/12 3:15 PM". How can I get another certificate? Why do I need one this was supposed to be free software?

Thank you in advance,
Maria

Answer (score 0):

Delete your debug certificate under ~/.android/debug.keystore ;

The Eclipse plugin should then generate a new certificate when you next try to build a debug package. You may need to clean and then build to generate the certificate.